# Prolog not showing full list of answer

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

When I run query `human(Who).` on the below `.pl` file

```
human(ann).
human(george).
human(mike).
```

I only get back `Who = ann .`

Instead of

```
Who = ann ;
Who = george ;
Who = mike.
```

Am using prolog 6.6.6. How do I get it to show the full list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you got was the following. Do you note the space before the dot?

```
Who = ann .
         ^ SPACE!!!
```

This space means: The query was aborted. Maybe you typed return. Or maybe you have a somewhat illconfigured terminal.

To better check this, try:

```
?- X = 1 ; X = 2 ; X = 3.
```

There you should get all three answers, too.  If not, it is definitely your terminal

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is the default behaviour of prolog.

The query

```
 ?-  findall(Object,Goal,List).
```

Should work for you.

Eg.

```
findall(X, human(X), L).
```

It will populate the list with all possible answers.

Comment: That's a little weird. I have watched multiple tutorials and they seems to return a list of answers with just `human(Who).`

Comment: This is an excellent website : http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse49